# log4net logger not writing my logs to file, but ASP.NET log messages are written

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, log4net

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor pages web site, and am trying to add log4net to it, but can't get logging to work properly. I have referenced the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore` Nuget package and associated dependencies.

I added a log4net.config file...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender"
            type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File"
           value="MyWebSite.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-7level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I changed Program.cs to look like this...

```cs
  public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) =>
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
          webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }).ConfigureLogging(builder => {
          builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
          builder.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
        });
  }
```

I tried using this on the site home page, as follows...

```cs
 public class IndexModel : PageModel {
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger) {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet() {
      _logger.LogDebug("Home page loading");
    }
  }
```

However, the log file did not contain the message I added.

I can see that logging is working to a degree, as the log file was created, and the first three lines were...

> 2020-10-18 16:27:59,052  INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime.? [?] - MESSAGE: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

> 2020-10-18 16:27:59,065  INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime.? [?] - MESSAGE: Hosting environment: Development

> 2020-10-18 16:27:59,066  INFO Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime.? [?] - MESSAGE: Content root path:

...but then I don't get anything else.

To check it was all being set up correctly, I added the following lines inside the `Onget()` method...

```cs
      ILoggerRepository repository = log4net.LogManager.GetAllRepositories().FirstOrDefault();
      RollingFileAppender appender = repository.GetAppenders().OfType<RollingFileAppender>().FirstOrDefault();
      string logFile = appender.File;
```

At run time, the `logFile` variable is correctly set to the path to the expected log file, so it looks like it has initialised fine.

I tried going the old-fashioned root and newing up an instance of the logger as follows...

```
log4NetLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(IndexModel));
```

...and this worked fine.

So, I can log, but only by creating the logger manually, not by injection.

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

**Update** Having just found out how to debug log4net, I added the following line in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startupcs`...

```
log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;
```

This resulted in the following being sent to the output panel...

```
log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a]. (.NET Framework [.NET Core 3.1.4] on Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363)
log4net: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d1104efbd0e675d]
log4net: Assembly [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d1104efbd0e675d] Loaded From [Not supported on .NET Core]
log4net: Assembly [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d1104efbd0e675d] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d1104efbd0e675d] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using XML element
log4net: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: Logger [root] Level string is [DEBUG].
log4net: Logger [root] level set to [name="DEBUG",value=30000].
log4net: Loading Appender [RollingFileAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]
log4net: Setting Property [File] to String value [MyWebSite.log]
log4net: Setting Property [AppendToFile] to Boolean value [True]
log4net: Setting Property [LockingModel] to object [log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock]
log4net: Setting Property [RollingStyle] to RollingMode value [Size]
log4net: Setting Property [MaxSizeRollBackups] to Int32 value [2]
log4net: Setting Property [MaximumFileSize] to String value [5MB]
log4net: Setting Property [StaticLogFileName] to Boolean value [True]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%date [%thread] %-7level %logger - %message%newline%exception]
log4net: Converter [date] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [thread] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [] ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=7,max=2147483647,leftAlign=True]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ - ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [exception] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout]
log4net: Searched for existing files in [PATHTOPROJECT]
log4net: curSizeRollBackups starts at [0]
log4net: Opening file for writing [PATHTOPROJECT\MyWebSite.log] append [True]
log4net: Created Appender [RollingFileAppender]
log4net: Adding appender named [RollingFileAppender] to logger [root].
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: PATHTOPROJECT
```

Not sure if this helps, as it doesn't seem to show any errors. The path is correct, and points to the log file that is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed the default logging level set in your appSettings.json to "Debug"? If it's set to "Information" then debug logging messages won't show.

Comment: Duh, how obvious is that! Thanks, that was the problem 