Log4Net not writing to file
I have the problem with Log4NET in combination with ASP.NET 7.0 that it doesn't write to my Logfile, but he creates the Logfile and writes to the console.
So I read a lot about assembly references, log4net layout patterns etc. but nothing worked. In StartupBase, I configure Log4Net by passing the log4net.config.
The log4net.config is found, I testet it by renaming .
After renaming, the file changed, too. So, I think the config file was found.
StartUpBase.cs
public class StartUpBase
{
   public ILog Logger { get; set;  }

   public void ConfigureServiceBase(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       var repo = LogManager.CreateRepository(
       Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));
       XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
       Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(StartUpBase));
       services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILog), Logger);
   }

}

Startup.cs
public class Startup : StartUpBase
{
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration) : base(env, configuration)
    {
        
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ConfigureServiceBase(services);
      
        ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
    }
}

Program.cs
  class ServiceTemplate
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

          BuildWebHost(args).Run();

      }

      public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
      {
          return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .Build();
      }
  }

Root Controller
[ApiController]
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 public class Root : Controller
 {
     public Root(ILogger<Root> Logger)
     {
         Logger.LogDebug("Hello DEBUG");
         Logger.LogInformation("Hello DEBUG");
         Logger.LogWarning("Hello DEBUG");
         Logger.LogError("Hello DEBUG");
     }
  }

log4net
<log4net debug="true">
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Repository\ShareSoftware\Logs\ServiceTemplate.log" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>


What exception does it crash with? Are you running under your own account or is this an IIS app? if so, is the app served from the same common path you log to?

It is not crashing, the application runs well. My problem is that Log4Net is not writing into my Logfile. In the program terminal, the log is printed, so the LogDebug function is reached. I am running it on my own account ( Visual Studio Debug). My Log Folder and My Application are both in C:/Repository/ShareSoftware.

It doesn't look like you have setup the logging dependency injection correctly, maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220727/log4net-logger-not-writing-my-logs-to-file-but-asp-net-log-messages-are-written and similar questions can help.

thank's, your answer gave me the final notice to my mistake, which I made. I created in StartUpBase a  Logger Instance with the type ILog (Log4Net). But in my Controller, I have binded a Logger from Type ILogger, which is from Microsoft.Extensions.Logger. Not it works :) Thanks

I found the reason. In my StartUpBase, I am binding an Logger Instance from Type ILog (Log4Net) to the service.AddSingleton(...). In my Controller, binded ILogger (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) in the constructor. This is a other Logger Library, so it can not work. After this little Fix it works:
   public Root(ILog Logger)
   {
       Logger.Debug("Hallo DEBUG");
       Logger.Info("Hallo DEBUG");
       Logger.Warn("Hallo DEBUG");
       Logger.Error("Hallo DEBUG");
   }

